# How to solve the IllegalDataException in jdom2 library?

Tags: java, xml, encoding, jdom, jdom-2

I am using jdom 2.0.6 version and received this IllegalDataException:

```
Error in setText for tokenization:
```

it fails on calling the setText() method.

```
Element text = new Element("Text");
text.setText(doc.getText());
```

It seems some characters in 'text' it doesn't accept. For two examples:

```
Originally Posted by Yvette H( 45) Odd socks, yes, no undies yes, no coat yes, no shoes odd. 
ParryOtter said: Posted
```

Should I specify encoding somewhere or for some other reasons?

Comment: Hi, I have same issue. I don't think it's directly a problem about encoding but rather about illegal characters in XML as said in org.jdom2.Verifier#checkCharacterData I'll Depending about your needs but in my case, I'll try to automatically locate the illegal character and remove it from the text until checkCharacterData(String text) returns null.

Answer (score 0):

In fact you just have to escape your text which contains illegal characters with CDATA :

```
Element text = new Element("Text");
text.setContent(new CDATA(doc.getText()));
```

The reverse operation (reading text escaped with CDATA is transparent in JDOM2, you won't have to escape it back).

For my tests I added an illegal character at the end of my text by creating one from hex value 0x2 like that :

```
String text = doc.getText();
int hex = 0x2;
text += (char) hex;
```